# Protoc not running via CMake

Tags: cmake, protocol-buffers

I'm trying to get my protobuf models to generate using CMake and am not sure what is happening. I've used this package before without trouble and followed documentation.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.13)
project(sockproto)

find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})
protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS commands.proto)
add_custom_target(protobuf_compilation DEPENDS ${PROTO_SRCS})
```

```sh
$ tree -L 1
.
├── CMakeCache.txt
├── CMakeFiles
├── cmake_install.cmake
├── include
├── Makefile
├── proto
└── tests
```

```sh
$ which protoc
/usr/bin/protoc
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed, protoc not run until PROTO_SRCS are added to executable or custom target as dependency.

Comment: According to your description, the code in the question is **correct**, isn't it? But for trigger `protobuf_compilation` target one need either to specify it explicitely: `make protobuf_compilation` or add `ALL` keyword to `add_custom_target` call, so the target will be built by default.